# Creating a function to automatize data extraction / to return a summarised dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset containing every sell the company does. For every month I would like to get a summarised dataframe with the name of the customer, the number of purchases the customer have made, and the total value of their purchase for the giving month. At the moment, I'm doing this by creating a single dataframe for each customer and joining all dataframes at the end, so my code looks something like this:

#'No. of Pucharses'

`Client2_April_NoPurchase = len(sells_data[(sells_data['Customer'] == 'Client2') & (sells_data['Month'] == 'Apr')])`

#'Total Value of Purchases (USD)'

`Client2_April_ValuePurchases = sells_data.loc[(sells_data['Customer'] == 'Client2') & (sells_data['Month'] == 'Apr'), 'Value of Purhcase (USD)'].sum()`

#raw_data

`Client2_Purchases_April_datadf = {'Customer': ['Client2'], 'Purchases (No.)': [(Client2_April_NoPurchase)], 'Value of Purhcase (USD)': [(Client2_April_ValuePurchases)]}`

#Dataframe

`Client2_Purchases_April = pd.DataFrame(Client2_Purchases_April_datadf, columns = ['Customer', 'Purchases (No.)', 'Value of Purchases (USD)'])`

I repeat this code for every client, which makes my tool very 'manually'. Is there a way to 'automate' this code? I though about creating a function but all the ones that I've tried haven't worked. Please also note that some customers have value of purchases in other currencies (AUD, CAD, ect), and some have value of purchases in several currencies at the same time (USD & CAD, etc).

Example of the dataset (sells_data):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBvqe.png)

Comment: groupby is your friend

Comment: Please provide a minimal example of sells_data.

Comment: thanks @ybml . Example added in the original question

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reproducible version of your dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'customer' : ['Client1', 'Client2', 'Client2', 'Client3', 'Client1', 'Client2'],
    'date' : ['08/04/2020', '14/04/2020', '14/04/2020', '15/04/2020', '14/04/2020', '14/04/2020'],
    'value_usd' : [50, 300, 20, np.nan, 95, 30],
    'value_gbp' : [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 20, np.nan, np.nan],
    'value_eur' : [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 10, np.nan],
    'value_hkd' : [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'value_cad' : [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
})
```

Using `groupby` you can now aggregate the data by client in several ways. This line counts the entries:

```
df.groupby(['customer']).agg(['count'])

          date value_usd value_gbp value_eur value_hkd value_cad
         count     count     count     count     count     count
customer                                                        
Client1      2         2         0         1         0         0
Client2      3         3         0         0         0         0
Client3      1         0         1         0         0         0
``
```